# How to use font awesome in html

Tags: html, css, button, icons, font-awesome

I can't make the arrow icon from font awesome into a button so I can't click it to move to another pages. Also when I can make it into button, I can't customize the color or the size in css. Here's my code in html.

```
<div class="arrow-back">
    <a href="./index4.html"><i class="fa-solid fa-circle-chevron-left"></i></a>
</div>
```

Can anyone help me how to make it into button so I can click and customize it?

Comment: Please share what you have already tried in CSS.

Comment: And why can’t you click it already? What’s happening in your case?

Answer (score 0):

Below an option for your requirement. Obviously, you can adjust the sizes to your liking.

```css
.arrow-back > a {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 2em;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="arrow-back">
  <a href="./index4.html"><i class="fa-solid fa-circle-chevron-left"></i></a>
</div>
```